# Get access from one network to another through server

Tags: networking, dhcp, interface

I have PC with two interfaces eth0 and wlan0. I set two different networks, on eth0 192.168.0.0, and on wlan0 192.168.1.0. I also configure DHCP server (isc-dhcp-server) and it works fine. When I connect via cable I got an address from 192.168.0.0 network (eg. 192.168.0.2), and when I connect via wifi I got an address from wlan0 network.

I want to connect one device (e.g. X) on the ethernet and another (e.g. Y) on wifi at the same time and have possibility to ping from device X the device Y.

I disable firewall by typing `ufw disable`, and I enable ip4 forward, but it doesn't help.

How can I ping device X from device Y?

Comment: @Yaron It looks similar but it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! Please [edit] your post to clarify how the called duplicate failed to solve your problem. "it doesn't help" is far from useful information. Exactly what you did and the results thereof are typically of far more use. Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: @ElderGeek it is a duplicate.

Comment: In that case I'm glad we were able to point you in the right direction. All the best to you and yours.